# List of y86 commands?

Tags: assembly, y86

I am looking for a way to convert some code into it's y86 equivalent.  The problem is I am having trouble finding a good list of y86 functions.  I can find some functions but not a good list of the main functions available.  Does anyone know where I could find such a list?

Comment: Yes, it is but I am still having trouble finding where there is a list of commands.

Comment: @pst I looked but is there a list of instructions there?

Comment: Voting to close as resource rec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Chapter 4: Processor Design (Preview)](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/ch4-preview.pdf) which is from [Computer Systems: A Programmers Perspective](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013034074X)<sup>1</sup> which has a great reference of all of the available functions.  You have to scroll down a ways to find the reference.  But it is there.

The instructions listed are:

```
halt
nop
rrmovl
irmovl
rmmovl
mrmovl
OPl (integer operation)
    addl
    subl
    andl
    xorl
jXXX (branch condition)
    jmp
    jle
    jl
    je
    jne
    jge
    jg
cmovXX (data transfer condition)
    cmovle
    cmovl
    cmove
    cmovne
    cmovge
    cmovg 
call
ret
pushl
popl
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This was authored by Randal E. Bryant and David R. O’Hallaron, who wrote an earlier paper that *omitted* the Data Transfer Conditional operators.

Comment: +1 For the nice link. I was trying to source the authors/publication and came across an older/work draft that omitted the `cmovXX` instructions, so care should be taken in *what* y86 instructions - including any extensions - are available.

Answer (score 4):

This is easily [the best resource I've found](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~reeves/CSE2421sp13/PracticeProblemsY86.pdf).

The document includes the instructions and their corresponding hex values, as well as setup code for someone writing y86 from scratch.

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70919423/y86-instructions-set-create-confusion