# y86 instructions set create confusion

Tags: architecture, cpu-registers, program-counter, y86

I am a beginner of computer architecture. I try to learn Y86 architecture. I got this [reference](https://y86tutoring.wordpress.com/y86-ia/) for the Y86 architecture. I did not understand the picture `Stage computation: Arith/log. ops`. I have studied the book `Computer Systems: A programmer's Perspective` but the things are not clear to me

1. M1[PC]
2. M1[PC+1] and other lines

As per the book, M1[x] indicates accessing (either reading or writing) 1 byte at memory location x. That means M1[PC] means accessing(either reading or writing) 1 byte at memory location program counter. Is that make sense?

1. valP <- PC+2

But why it is PC+2 and not any other integer.

I also came to know from the book `In the fetch stage, we do not require a constant word, and so valP is computed as PC + 2`

But then again `It is also possible fetches a 4byte constant word valC`

So suppose, there is another line in the above example after rA:rB<-M1[PC+1] is valC<- M4[PC+2]
then what will be the next line valP<-PC +______

Here I try to solve a  small program following the link I refer here

```
Stage:  addq V, rB

Fetch:  icode : ifun ← M1[PC]

        rA : rB ← M1[PC+1]
        valC ← M8[PC+2]
        valP ← PC + 10

Decode: valB ← R[rB] 

Execute:    valE ← valB + valC

Memory:  

Write back: R[rB] ← valE 

PC update:  PC ← valP
```

Edited: I edit this question and try to understand how much knowledge I gain from the link.

Is my code alright?

Comment: It's `PC+2` because the arithmetic/logical instructions are 2 bytes in length. See the instruction set table earlier in the linked page. For other instructions that take a `valC` you will need additional increment to `valP`.

Comment: I edited my question and try to solve a code block. Can you please take a look am I got it alright or partially correct?

Comment: There is no `addq V, rB` unless you are using a different ISA than what you linked. Also your execute uses `valA` instead of `valC`.

Comment: I have edited valA with valC. Is it alright?

Comment: Looks okay now.

Comment: I have understood from your previous comments why I need to write PC+10 in fetch cycle. Can you please explain it once again? I would like to see am I in the right track or not. Thank you.

Comment: 2 bytes for the instruction, 8 bytes for the `valC` operand.

Comment: Can you please take a look one of my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70921787/bubble-sort-implemented-by-y86-program-code